# Ordenar listas en Python 3 dependiendo de otra lista

Tags: python

Estimados, tengo varias listas que dependen una de otra, por ejemplo en una lista tengo un código y en otra tenga la fecha de ese código. Mi problema es que tuve que agregar una nueva lista de códigos que igual tiene su lista de fechas. Mi intención es crear una lista sola de fechas ordenadas cronológicamente pero que mantenga la posición respecto a su lista de códigos.

Yo lo que estaba haciendo era pegar al final la nueva lista de fechas y nueva lista de códigos quedando una sola gran lista de códigos y otra gran lista de fechas, así:

```
    for i in range(len(codigo2)): #Union lista principal FDE, Fecha y Status
        CODIGOS.append(codigo2[i])
        FECHAS.append(fechas2[i])
```

Pero al hacer esto el orden cronológico se pierde ya que solo estoy añadiendo al final los nuevos códigos y fechas. Conocen una forma de ordenar una lista y mantener esas nuevas posiciones para otra lista.

Comment: Jorge, me parece que tu problema es un poco más profundo, las listas tiene un orden natural, que es el orden en que ingresaste cada elemento, si ingresas una fecha en una lista y un código en otra al mismo tiempo, ambas van a estar sincronizadas, y el item en una posición de una lista se corresponderá al elemento de la otra en la misma posición. Una vez que ordenes una de las listas (la de fecha), pierdes toda sincronía entre ambas. Tal vez lo que debas es replantearte el objeto contenedor y pensar en una lista de tuplas, donde cada tupla sea codigo y fecha.

Comment: Aparte de lo que comenta Patricio, se que soy repetitivo :) pero ¿Por qué no usas Pandas concatenado dataframes simplemente y luego ordenando? Depende de donde vengan tus dos listas pero creo que es mucho más simple.  Lo que quieres hacer es posible pero altamente ineficiente. Se puede hacer mediante lo que se conoce como transformada de Schwartzian usando zip.

Comment: @FJSevilla pero se puede? es que cargo desde 2 fuentes de datos distintas, ambas fuentes las ordeno con Pandas, pero obligatoriamente creo listas y ahí tengo el problema. Originalmente la segunda lista la debo trabajar para mezclar con la primera. Pero lo veré ahora, haber si puedo.

Comment: Jorge si se puede, la idea ya la esboza @César en su respuesta. ¿Usas python 3?

Comment: Hago demasiadas operaciones con la nueva lista, ya que no es igual a la primera, si lo hago de un comienzo el tiempo de la compialción aumenta mucho. Estaba viendo zip() ahí logro unir todo, podría ordenar cronológicamente y luego separar las listas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te he comentado es posible usando la [transformada de Schwartzian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) que aunque la idea viene de Perl en Python se puede implementar usando `zip`.

La idea es simple, se usa `zip` para obtener las parejas de elementos y se les aplica `sorted`. Esto nos da una lista con las parejas ordenadas por el primer iterable pasado a `zip`(a igualdad de este elemento, se usa el siguiente).

Hecho esto, desempaquetamos la lista retornada por `sorted` y pasamos todos sus elementos como argumentos a `zip` para volver a obtener dos listas usando los elementos de las tuplas. En Python se puede desempaquetar un iterable usando `*` delante de él.

Lo único complicado es entender el funcionamiento de `zip`, creo que con un par de ejemplos se puede aclarar mejor que con palabras:

---

```
>>> a = (1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> b = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
>>> c = list(zip(a, b))
>>> c
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd')]
>>> d, e = zip(*c)
>>> d
(1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> e
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

`zip(*c)` es equivalente a:

```
zip((1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'))
```

---

Un ejemplo de como ordenar usando la idea anterior basado en tu código:

```
from datetime import date

# Las dos listas originales
CODIGOS = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
FECHAS = [date(2017, 7, 24), date(2017, 7, 25), date(2017, 7, 26), date(2017, 7, 27), date(2017, 7, 28)]

# Concatenas nuevos valores
CODIGOS.extend([7, 10, 24, 14])
FECHAS.extend([date(2017, 7, 30), date(2017, 7, 20), date(2017, 8, 1), date(2017, 7, 21)])

# Ordenamos aplicando lo explicado antes
FECHAS, CODIGOS = map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(FECHAS, CODIGOS))))
```

**Salida:**

> >>> FECHAS
>   [datetime.date(2017, 7, 20), datetime.date(2017, 7, 21), datetime.date(2017, 7, 24), datetime.date(2017, 7, 25), datetime.date(2017, 7, 26), datetime.date(2017, 7, 27), datetime.date(2017, 7, 28), datetime.date(2017, 7, 30), datetime.date(2017, 8, 1)]
>   >>> CODIGOS
>   [10, 14, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 24]

Si te fijas uso `list.extend` para concatenar las listas, considera usar esto en tu código en vez del ciclo `for` y `append` que usas ahora.

Comment: Buenisima, gracias!

Comment: @JorgePonti si tienes problemas de eficiencia habría que intentar usar Pandas u otra alternativa. Aunque la "magia" de Python haga esto en una linea tan "simple " como `map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(FECHAS, CODIGOS))))` ni te imaginas el trabajo que hay detrás... :). Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Define una clase `Entrada`

```
class Entrada:
    def __init__(codigo, fecha):
        self.codigo = codigo
        self.fecha = fecha
```

Luego si tienes dos listas con entradas puedes mezclarlas y ordenarlas de la siguiente manera

```
entradas = [
    Entrada('code 1', 234567890),
    Entrada('code 2', 726578236),
    Entrada('code 3', 328957359)
]

entradas2 = [
    Entrada('code 4', 789275883),
    Entrada('code 5', 349092090),
    Entrada('code 6', 952893850)
]

for i in range(len(entradas2)):
    entradas.append(entradas2[i])

entradas.sort(key=lambda entrada: entrada.fecha)
```

Answer (score 1):

Si las posiciones de ambas listas coinciden, es decir, el código en `CODIGOS[x]` corresponde a la fecha en `FECHAS[x]`, lo que puedes hacer es usar [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> codigos
[10, 20, 30, 40]
>>> fechas
[datetime.date(2017, 7, 15), datetime.date(2017, 7, 20), datetime.date(2017, 7, 1)]
>>> zip(codigos, fechas)
[(10, datetime.date(2017, 7, 15)), (20, datetime.date(2017, 7, 20)), (30, datetime.date(2017, 7, 1))]
```

Comment: Siempre coinciden, lo que pasa es que como agrego una nueva lista debo volver a ordenar todo.

Comment: @JorgePonti esas listas se crean por separado en distintas funciones?

Comment: Nacen de pandas ordenadas, luego las transformo en listas para trabajarlas pero siempre están ordenadas, pero luego tengo otra lista nueva que debo mezclarla con la lista original y se debe a ordenar todo nuevamente

Comment: @JorgePonti por qué no usas un diccionario? Así tendrías la fecha que sería la llave del diccionario y el código que sería el valor del diccionario. Cuando quieras usarlas de forma ordenada simplemente iteras ordenando las llaves del diccionario (cronológicamente)

Comment: Existen fechas iguales, al hacerlo en un diccionario si no me equivoco la clave se reemplazaría. Pero la función zip() que agregaste no funcionaría?

Answer (score 1):

Jorge, el siguiente código explica mi comentario y te aporta una solución a tu pregunta. Coincido con @FjSevilla, si ya estás usando `pandas`, por que transformar los datos en listas para luego hacer este ordenamiento? `pandas` ofrece mucha funcionalidad para operar con `dataframes`, tal vez tengas que investigar por ese lado, sino esto seguramente te pueda ayudar

```
codigo = [1, 2, 4]
fechas = ["2017-01-01", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-04"]

codigo2 = [3]
fechas2 = ["2017-01-03"]


print("Las dos listas con el orden natural y sincronizadas")
print("\n".join([str(e) for e in zip(codigo, fechas)]))

print("Agrego las listas nuevas")
print("\n".join([str(e) for e in zip(codigo2, fechas2)]))

fechas = fechas + fechas2
codigo = codigo + codigo2

print("El resultado sigue manteniendo el orden natural, sincronizadas, pero ahora la fecha esta desordenada")
print("\n".join([str(e) for e in zip(codigo, fechas)]))


print("Si ordeno la lista de fechas pierdo la sincronía con la de códigos")
fechas.sort()
print("\n".join([str(e) for e in zip(codigo, fechas)]))

print("Si armo tuplas (codigo,fecha) puedo ordenar sin problema por una de las columnas")
tuplelist = [e for e in zip(codigo, fechas)]
tuplelist.sort(key=lambda tuplelist: tuplelist[1])
print("\n".join([str(e) for e in tuplelist]))
```

Esta es la salida:

```
Las dos listas con el orden natural y sincronizadas
(1, '2017-01-01')
(2, '2017-01-02')
(4, '2017-01-04')
Agrego las listas nuevas
(3, '2017-01-03')
El resultado sigue manteniendo el orden natural, sincronizadas, pero ahora la fecha esta desordenada
(1, '2017-01-01')
(2, '2017-01-02')
(4, '2017-01-04')
(3, '2017-01-03')
Si ordeno la lista de fechas pierdo la sincronía con la de códigos
(1, '2017-01-01')
(2, '2017-01-02')
(4, '2017-01-03')
(3, '2017-01-04')
Si armo tuplas (codigo,fecha) puedo ordenar sin problema por una de las columnas
(1, '2017-01-01')
(2, '2017-01-02')
(4, '2017-01-03')
(3, '2017-01-04')
```

Toma nota que cada "codigo" se corresponde con el día en la "fecha". Al ordenar la "fecha" perdimos la "sincronía", es como cuando ordenas por una columna en Excel y olvidas indicar las otras. La solución es mantener una estructura de datos que permita que "codigo" y "fecha" estén relacionados. Una posibilidad es usar las "tuplas", con esto: `tuplelist = [e for e in zip(codigo, fechas)]` transformas las dos listas en otra lista de tuplas, algo así `[(codigo, fecha), (codigo, fecha),...]`. Con esta estructura ya puedes hacer: `tuplelist.sort(key=lambda tuplelist: tuplelist[1])` para ordenar todo por la fecha (columna 2).  Por último, si quieres volver a dejar todo como las listas originales, simplemente hay que hacer un "unzip":

```
codigo, fecha = [list(e) for e in zip(*tuplelist)]
```